# is there any other way to submit my dynamically added input fields?

Tags: php, submission

i have tried to create form input fields dynamically and i succeeded but when all other fields are being submitted, only the dynamically created fields are not please help out.. thanks..

my javascript is working fine, its creating the fileds just fine inside the modal..
the problem is when i am submitting it only the dynamically added fields are not submitted..

```
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' method="post"> 
 
 <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
      <h6> Contact person in case of emergency</h6
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Contact person" required=""  pattern="([A-Z][a-z]*\s*[A-Z]*[a-z]*\s*[0-9]*)" title="Alphbetical characters only, capitalize first letter, full name then phone number" value="<?php echo $info[0]['contactperson'];?>" name="contactperson" type="text">
     </div>
    </div>
    
      
       
    
    <input class="form-control" hidden placeholder="familymembers"  id="fm" value="<?php echo $info[0]['familymembers'];?>"  name="familymembers" type="number">
        
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <h6>&nbsp;</h6>
              <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#seefmlist"><button class="btn btn-success">Edit Family Members List</button></a>
          </div>
        </div>
    
    //this is a script to add new input fields daynamically
    
    
     
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
          function getfmembers(){
          var fn=document.getElementById('fm').value;
             
          for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
          document.getElementById('fm').value++;
          k=document.getElementById('fm').value;
         var btn='<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="fmlis" placeholder="Name of the family member" id="'+k+'"  type="text"></div>';
    
             $("#after").after(btn);
             alert(document.getElementById(k).name);
    
             } 
              }
     function removefmembers(){
       var fn=document.getElementById('fm').value;
    
          $("input").remove("#"+fn); 
           document.getElementById('fm').value--;
        }
    
        </script>
    // this is the modal to submit the inputs and its inside the form tag
    <div class="modal fade" id="seefmlist" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Family Members List</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <span onclick="getfmembers()" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Add Member</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <span onclick="removefmembers()" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete Last Member</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        
            <div id="after">
            <?php
     $flist=explode(",",$info[0]['familylist']);
      if (count($flist)>1) {
      for ($qq=0; $qq < count($flist)-1 ; $qq++) { 
        echo '<div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="'.($qq+1).'"  value="'.$flist[$qq+1].'"  name="fmlist'.($qq+1).'" type="text"></div>';
                           
                            }
                            }
    
    
              ?>
    
         
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    </div>
    
    <div class="text-center">
                      <button type="submit" name='submitupdate' class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Update Employee information</button>
                    </div>
                 
                  </form>
```

Comment: Your HTML above is invalid. You failed to correctly close the first `h6` tag (`<h6> Contact person in case of emergency</h6`) and there are an unbalanced number of opening/closing DIV tags

Answer (score 0):

line 31 :
`for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {`
only runs once, if you wanted to have this add more than one you will need to fix

also **probably the problem you are hung up on**
line 34 : `name="fmlis"` later in your code you have `name="fmlist'.($qq+1).'` so, on line 34 you probably want to concat `k+1` to the name...